# Fundamental Lemma of homological Algebra, what is $H_0f$ supposed to mean?

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

I am currently attending a lecture in homological algebra, where we discussed the fundamental lemma of homological algebra (i will just cite the relevant part of the theorem):

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. Let $M$ be an object in
> $\mathcal{A}$ and let $P_*\to M$ be a projective resolution of $M$,
> that is: $$\cdots \to P_n\to \cdots\to P_1 \to P_0\to M \to 0.$$
>
> Let $N$ be another object in $\mathcal{A}$ and let $Q_*\to N$ be any
> resolution of $N$.
>
> Let $f\colon M\to N$ be a morphism in $\mathcal{A}$. Then the
> following holds:
>
> (1) There exists a morphism $\varphi\colon P_*\to Q_*$ of chain
> complexes, s.t. $H_0\varphi = f\colon M\to N$.

I understand everything, except this:

> $H_0\varphi = f\colon M\to N$.

What is that supposed to mean? I know that we can apply the Homology-functor $H_*$ to any chain complex in order to measure the exactness of the chain complex in each degree and any morphism $\varphi_*\colon C_*\to D_*$ between two chain complexes $C_*, D_*$ induces a morphism $H_*\varphi_*$ in homology.

But a resolution of an object in $\mathcal{A}$ is exact in each degree anyway, thus, applying the homology functor returns a long exact sequence containing only trivial elements, doesn't it?

How can i obtain $H_0\varphi = f\colon M\to N$?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The morphism $\phi=\phi_\cdot$ is explicitly:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\color{blue}{P_\cdot}        @.   @. 0        @<<< P_0        @<<< P_1        @<<< P_2        @<<< \dots \\
@V \color{blue}{\phi_\cdot} VV  @.   @. @VV\phi_0V      @VV\phi_1V      @VV\phi_2V \\
\color{blue}{Q_\cdot}        @.   @. 0        @<<<  Q_0        @<<< Q_1        @<<< Q_2        @<<< \dots \\
\end{CD}
No we apply the functor $H_0$ on the above blue morphism.

We obtain a map, $H_0(\phi_\cdot)$, with domain $H_0(P_\cdot)$ and codomain $H_0(Q_\cdot)$.

Since $P_\cdot $ is a (projective) resolution of $M$, we have $H_0(P_\cdot)\cong M$. (So $H_0$ is a well defined functor only when considered to have values in the category of isomorphism classes in the abelian category $\mathcal A$.)
We fix this $M$ as a representative for $H_0(P_\cdot)$.

Similarly, since $Q_\cdot $ is a (projective) resolution of $N$, we have $H_0(Q_\cdot)\cong N$, and we fix this $N$ as a representative for $H_0(Q_\cdot)$.

Now the claim in $(1)$ in the OP is a restriction for $\phi$, which constrains the fact, that (after the choices of $M,N$ as representatives, and i will now write $H_0(P_\cdot)= M$, and $H_0(Q_\cdot)=N$, and lift everything to $\mathcal A$,
and possibly after composing "inside" $M$ and/or $N$ with some isomorphism) the induced map $H_0(\phi_\cdot)$ from $H_0(P_\cdot)= M$ to $H_0(Q_\cdot)=N$ is the map $f:M\to N$.

This is equivalent to the fact that we have a commutative "extended diagram":

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0  @<<<  M      @<<< P_0        @<<< P_1        @<<< P_2        @<<< \dots \\
@.       @VfVV       @VV\phi_0V      @VV\phi_1V      @VV\phi_2V \\
0   @<<< N      @<<<  Q_0       @<<< Q_1        @<<< Q_2        @<<< \dots \\
\end{CD}

In other words, $f$ "lifts" to $\phi_0$.

Comment: Hi @dan_fulea, thanks a lot for your answer. Did you happen to forget the objects $M$ and $N$ in your first diagram? Or is that intentionally?

Comment: Ah, i've missed your line about the extended diagram, my apologies. Would you mind elaborating why $H_0(P_\bullet)\cong M$? I know what a projective object is and i know its definition, i.e. it factors through any epimorphism. But why does that imply $H_0(P_\bullet)\cong M$?

How does the first diagram look like after applying $H_0$? Doesn't it turn every $P_i$ into a trivial object?

Comment: Since $P$ is a (projective) resolution of $M$, the following is an **exact** sequence:$$\dots\to P_2\to P_1\to P_0\to M\to 0\ .$$ In particular, we can "cut" it in two exact sequences,$$\dots\to P_2\to P_1\to \operatorname{Ker}d\to 0\text{ and }0\to P_0/\operatorname{Im} d\to M\to 0\ .$$(Here, pick the correct $d$-morphisms for the kerner and the image.) The isomorphism in the middle of the exact diagram $0\to P_0/\operatorname{Im} d\to M\to 0$ is the isomorphism $H_0(P)\cong M$.

Comment: Ahh, of course. Thanks! I should have computed $H_0(P_\bullet)$ carefully by hand, then i wouldn't have missed it. In fact, i have done exactly this particular argument countless of times but somehow confused myself in this particular case working with resolutions. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciating it.